# Select top x % of values per group - retain row ID

Tags: r

I am trying to identify the top 15% of scores for each watershed but retain the polygon ID when I print the results.

```
# here's a small example dataset (called "data"):

 polygon watershed score
        1         1    61
        2         1    81
        3         1    16
        4         2    18
        5         2    12
        6         3    78
        7         3    81
        8         3    20
        9         3    97
       10         3    95

# I obtain the top 15% using this method:

top15 <- (data %>% select(watershed, score) %>%
  group_by(watershed) %>%
  arrange(watershed, desc(score)) %>%
  filter(score > quantile(score, 0.15)))


# results look like this:

      <int> <int>
1         1    81
2         1    61
3         2    18
4         3    97
5         3    95
6         3    81
7         3    78
```

How can I include the column "polygon" when I print the results?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Just do `data %>% group_by(watershed) %>% filter(score > quantile(score, 0.15))`

Comment: hm, top 15% - imho this relates to the 0.85-quantile.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the clarification around the top 85% vs 15%. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your statement you selected only `watershed` and `score` but excluded `polygon`. So remove the `select` statement and you should get what you want. Additionally the arrange doesn't add value so I removed it:

```
library(dplyr)
mdat <- structure(list(polygon = 1:10, 
                       watershed = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                       score = c(61L, 81L, 16L, 18L, 12L, 78L, 81L, 20L, 97L, 95L)), 
                       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))


mdat %>% 
  group_by(watershed) %>%
  filter(score > quantile(score, 0.15))
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
# # Groups:   watershed [3]
#   polygon watershed score
#     <int>     <int> <int>
# 1       1         1    61
# 2       2         1    81
# 3       4         2    18
# 4       6         3    78
# 5       7         3    81
# 6       9         3    97
# 7      10         3    95
```